# How to get the address of LoadLibraryA in Windows XP with Python 3?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to get the address of `LoadLibraryA` in Windows XP using Python 3, for which I wrote the following code:

```
from ctypes import *

kernel32 = windll.kernel32

h_kernel32 = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll")
load_address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32, "LoadLibraryA")
print(h_kernel32)
print(load_address)
```

But the result is `0 0`. How can I solve this problem? Are there other methods to get the address?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious to know why you would use `LoadLibraryA` over `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, do you mean `LoadLibraryW`? `LoadLibrary` doesn't exist.

Comment: @eryksun: Sure. I guess I'm just used to the include/interface files replacing everything for me.

Comment: Use either `cast(kernel32.LoadLibraryA, c_void_p).value` or `c_void_p.from_buffer(kernel32.LoadLibraryA).value`. But generally if you need to pass this address to a function just directly pass the function pointer `kernel32.LoadLibraryA`.

Comment: BTW, your ctypes code isn't working because it's fundamentally flawed. It's passing 16-bit `wchar_t` strings (it's Python 3) to `GetModuleHandleA` and `GetProcAddress`, which both require 8-bit `char` strings (i.e. Python 3 `bytes`). Plus it's not 64-bit safe, since it's using a pointer value cast as the default 32-bit `c_int` result/argument type.

Comment: @eryksun thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fully specifies the functions you are calling and works correctly using 64-bit Python 3.  Note the use of byte strings for `LPCSTR`:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as win

kernel32 = windll.kernel32

GetModuleHandleA = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA
GetModuleHandleA.argtypes = [win.LPCSTR]
GetModuleHandleA.restype = win.HMODULE

GetProcAddress = kernel32.GetProcAddress
GetProcAddress.argtypes = [win.HMODULE,win.LPCSTR]
GetProcAddress.restype = c_void_p

h_kernel32 = GetModuleHandleA(b'kernel32')
load_address = GetProcAddress(h_kernel32, b'LoadLibraryA')
print('{:016X}'.format(h_kernel32))
print('{:016X}'.format(load_address))
```

Output:

```
0000000077A00000
0000000077A16520
```

If you wanted to call the wide version of `GetModuleHandle` (byte string not used):

```
GetModuleHandleW = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [win.LPCWSTR]
GetModuleHandleW.restype = win.HMODULE

h_kernel32 = GetModuleHandleW('kernel32')
```

Comment: OK, but why would you use this instead of just passing `kernel32.LoadLibraryA` as an argument? Or cast to `c_void_p` if the integer address is required for something (not sure what that would be).